# Passing to correct view controller on table view datasource selection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am loading table view cell with two different plist based on selection -

Problem is this. In **MoreScreenOptionsData plist** all elements are there and in **Guest_More plist** less items r there. so based on condition i m loading array.

Now when table gets load in both scenario login and logout, when row is selected it always redirect to **MoreScreenOptionsData plist** row index value. it is not redirecting to **Guest_More plist** plist array index.

if i load guest screen

**Scenario- if user is signed in or not**

```
- (NSArray *)moreScreenElements
 {
  NSString *plistPath;

  if ([VCConfiguration isUserAlreadyLoggedIn])
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MoreScreenOptionsData" ofType:@"plist"];
else
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Guest_More" ofType:@"plist"];

   moreScreenItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
 return moreScreenItems;
 }
```

**// Table View Row selection**

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case RowSelectedMethodMyOrder:
    {
        VCMyOrderViewController *myOrderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCMyOrderViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myOrderVC animated:YES];
    }
        break;

    case RowSelectedMethodMyAddresses:
    {
        VCMyAddressViewController* infoController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCMyAddressViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:infoController animated:YES];
    }
        break;

    case  RowSelectedMethodTrackOrder:
    {
        VCTrackOrderViewController *myOrderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCTrackOrderViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myOrderVC animated:YES];
    }
        break;

    case  RowSelectedMethodMyWallet:
    {

    }
        break;

    case RowSelectedMethodSetting:
    {

    }
        break;

    case RowSelectedMethodInviteFriends:
    {

    }
        break;

    case RowSelectedMethodRatetheApp:
    {
    }
        break;

    case RowSelectedMethodHelp:
    {
    }
        break;

    case RowSelectedMethodLogout:
    {
        [VCConfiguration clearLoggedUserData];
        moreScreenItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self moreScreenElements]];
        [self.tblMore reloadData];

        VCLoginViewController * loginVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCLoginViewController"];
        [loginVC setIsLoginForCart:NO];
        UINavigationController * navControllerLogin = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
        [navControllerLogin setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        [self presentViewController:navControllerLogin animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you need to keep condition based on login or not , like you did in `moreScreenElements` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
      if ([VCConfiguration isUserAlreadyLoggedIn]) {
         //Here you can write code for selecting MoreScreenOptionsData plist table cell
      } else {
          //Here you can write code for selecting Guest_More plist table cell 
      }
    }
```

Let me know if you need more assistence

**Edit**

After a long discussion with @imran, he need to do same actions based on row number and value so I suggested him same index kay and value in his both  plists and use the index key to judge your action in cell selection.

Comment: if user is not loged in i could go inside switch loop cases .my code as u said . it throw out of the switch case http://paste.ubuntu.com/14162030/

Comment: what exactly do you have issue ?"it throw out of the switch case" means ? if your indexpath.row is equal to any of your switch case , that will execute

Comment: if i select  if user not loged in plist data source index then it s not redirecting to controller. on particular row selection.i have given my code above

Comment: why 2 switch it s not good way, i guess in one switch it should be done.

Comment: See , you have two cases 1) LoggedIn 2)Gest  . If case: LoggedIn, you have different actions  and same for Gest. If you have common actions in both cases , you don't need two switch cases . If you need different actions , you need to implement two

Comment: then how can i frame conditon sir . plz could u let me know by code. i need to pass to correct view controller on row selection

Comment: i have to redirect to specific view controller based on row selction thats y i used enum and switch

Comment: can I see your both plists and enum? so I can create sample code sample and give you in 15min

Comment: thanks it does work by adding index key in plist file.